# form validation failed on edit in cakephp2

Tags: forms, validation, cakephp, edit

```
'employees_firstname' => array(
    'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
    'required' => true,
    'allowEmpty' => false,
    'on' => '',
    'message' => 'This field is required'
)
```

This is my validation. It works fine when adding. But when I am editing the validation error is showing even if the field has value. Whats the issue?

```
function edit_employee($employees_id)
    {
       debug($this->request->data);
        $business_accounts = $this->BusinessAccount->get_business_accounts();
        $business_domains = $this->BusinessDomain->get_business_domains();
        $designations = $this->Designation->get_designations();
        $work_locations = $this->EmployeesWorkLocation->get_worklocations();
        //$employees = $this->Employee->get_user_details();
        $employees = $this->Employee->get_employee_details($employees_id);
        $employees_details = $this->EmployeesDetail->get_employee_personal_details($employees_id);
        $countries = $this->Country->get_countries();
        $additional_data = array(
                        'business_accounts' => $business_accounts,
                        'business_domains' => $business_domains,
                        'designations' => $designations,
                        'work_locations' => $work_locations,
                        'supervisors' => $employees,
                        'countries' => $countries,
                        'employees' => $employees,
                        'employees_details' => $employees_details
                     );
        $this->set($additional_data);
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Calpinemate - Admin');
        $this->layout = 'admin_console';
       // echo $employees_id;
        $this->Employee->id = $employees_id;
        //$this->Employee->save($this->params['data']['Employee']);
         //print_r($this->data);
        if(!empty($this->data)){ 
            if(isset($this->params['data']['add'])){
                if($this->Employee->validates(array('fieldList' => array('employees_firstname','employees_lastname','employees_emailaddress','employees_password','employees_code','employees_mobile')))){
                    echo "IN";
                $fileOK = $this->uploadFiles('img/Employees', $this->data['File'], $this->data['Employee']['employees_code']);
                if (array_key_exists('urls', $fileOK)) {
                    $this->request->data['Employee']['employees_image'] = $fileOK['urls'][0];
                }

                $this->Employee->save($this->params['data']['Employee']);

                $this->request->data['EmployeesDetail']['employees_id'] = $this->Employee->id;
                $this->EmployeesDetail->save($this->params['data']['EmployeesDetail']);
                $this->Session->setFlash("Employee  Details Updated Successfully!");
                $this->redirect('employee');
                }
            }
            elseif(isset($this->params['data']['cancel'])){
                $this->redirect('employee');
            }
        } 
    }
```

This is the function in controller

```
echo $this->Form->create('Employee', array('url' => array('controller' => 'MasterConsole', 'action' => 'edit_employee',$employees[0]['Employee']['employees_id']),'type' => 'file'));

    <div class="listing1">
         <div class="list_grid">First name</div>
         <div class="list_grid7"><?php echo $this->Form->input('employees_firstname',array('type' => 'text','label' => false,'default' => isset($employees) ? $employees[0]['Employee']['employees_firstname'] : '')); ?></div>  


</div>
```

This is the code in the view file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add `'on' => ''` unless you are specifying create or update only.

Try removing that part completely.  Also, make sure that the data for the field is being properly passed to the model when you edit.  In your edit method for the controller, add a debug at the top to print out the data and check that it is actually coming through in the correct field:

```
debug($this->request->data);
```

Otherwise, please post the edit method of your controller and your view code.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question with the code of controller and view . Pls help